# Solr find most used words

Tags: solr, solr4

I need to find the most used 10 words in Solr collection.
I tried,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=content1&numTerms=10
```

It gives results. But it gives the words which are appear in most docs. If there were duplicated words in a doc, they won't be counted.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think that the duplicate words are counted. But you do not ask solr to show you the duplicates.You might try to use reportDocCount=true parameter:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=content1&numTerms=10&reportDocCount=true
```

Please notice that the deleted occurence will be show if you do not optimize your index.

[See the LukeRequestHandler doc on solr:](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler#numTerms)